# XSD: How do you make an element tag depend on the preceding element?

Tags: xml, xsd

The structure I want is something like this.

```
<root>
   ... 
   <animaltype>BIRD</animaltype>
   <birdname>eagle<birdname>
   ...
</root>
```

or

```
<root>
    ...
    <animaltype>LIZARD</animaltype>
    <reptilename>iguana</reptilename>
    ...
</root>
```

Most of what i've found on the internet only lets me create my own bird or lizard element which would be another level like:

```
<lizard>
     <name>iguana</name>
</lizard>
```

Comment: Do you have fixed values for `animaltype`?

Comment: yup, i have fixed values.

Comment: Not sure or used for myself, but you may try with simple type restriction. Please see if either [this](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Value_equality_-_and_following_siblings) or [this](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596002527/creating-simple-types.html) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not possible.

I tried the below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="animaltype" type="xs:string" fixed="BIRD"/>
                        <xs:element name="birdname" type="xs:string">
                    </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="animaltype" type="xs:string" fixed="LIZARD"/>
                        <xs:element name="reptilename" type="xs:string">
                     </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This does not seem to work. Seems to be validation https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/#cos-nonambig that name cannot be ambiguous.

In my opinion the best solution is as you have mentioned have different names for animal and bird elements or have a more relaxed schema.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="root" >
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="animaltype" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:choice>
             <xs:element name="birdname" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
             <xs:element name="reptilename" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
         </xs:choice>
         </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: wouldn't that allow animaltype of reptile to have a birdname tag?

Comment: @Samuel you are correct. I am trying to provide you the next best solution. In my answer the first line states that I think what you want to achieve is not possible.